# node create multiple tcp connections, hard to identify which connection it is in the call back

Tags: node.js, tcp

I need to make 3 tcp connections, it's hard to tell which connection is successful in the call back for "connect" event.

```
var clients = [];
var ports = [81,82,83];
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    clients[i] = net.createConnection(ports[i], '127.0.0.1');
    clients[i].on('connect', function(conn) {
            console.log("connect is setup");
            console.log(conn); //it's always undefined, why???
            //need to set different data to the different connections
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument provided to the `connect` event is a potential connection error, so, you're checking if there is an error. If I recall correctly, `console.log(this);` has information about the socket. Your main reference to the socket is also `clients[i]`

Comment: Sorry couldn't vote up since I don't have the permission yet to do so.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it figured out.